# I am trying to implement authentication in django using django_cas_ng, and also provide a option for all-auth for google login

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, django-allauth

My requirement is to have a core app to manage authentication, which should include google authentication (all-auth in django) and django_cas_ng (CAS authentication).

Now I want to be able to use this authentication app for multiple projects (CAS system).
I should register only for one app , and should be able to login to another app using the same username and password. (CAS auth system).

```py
  path('', django_cas_ng.views.LoginView.as_view(), name='cas_ng_login'),
  path('accounts/logout', django_cas_ng.views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='cas_ng_logout'),
```

I the url cas_ng_login redirects me to `CAS_SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/accounts/'`, where I have the google authentication implemented.

[image]